# MonoDevelop crashing over High Sierra (OSX 10.13)

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am facing an issue from yesterday after updating system to latest macOS 10.13 beta with unity monoDevelop below is what i am getting as crash report.

```
Process:               mono-sgen [9057]
Path:                  /tmp/*/mono
Identifier:            com.unity.monodevelop
Version:               5.9.6 (5.9.6)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           mono-sgen [9057]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-06-15 11:43:09.345 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13 (17A264c)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        ACA523AB-96B9-4E46-8D2A-A2210B9A181A

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5715E1CB-BBDF-4E3C-9CEE-8F8C01ADD64D

Time Awake Since Boot: 36000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000d9d1efbd
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0xd9d1efbd:
    Stack                  00000000bf7ee000-00000000bffe5000 [ 8156K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--> 
    Submap                 00000000ffff0000-00000000ffff1000 [    4K] r--/r-- SM=PRV  process-only VM submap

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0xa7617f6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa77346dd pthread_kill + 307
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0xa756881e abort + 133
3   mono                            0x000dc435 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 757
4   mono                            0x001282a2 mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception + 162
5   mono                            0x0002890e mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 446
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0xa7728fcb _sigtramp + 43
7   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
8   mono                            0x00028750 mono_sigill_signal_handler + 48
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x9524f536 _NSAddExceptionHandlerForLock + 21
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x9157d276 _NSAppKitLock + 78
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x913c4ecd -[NSApplication _addWindow:] + 50
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x913c47d0 -[NSWindow _commonInitFrame:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 295
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x913c33e9 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 940
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x9142ccaf -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 67
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x913c3033 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 72
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x9142cc5a -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 93
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x9142c426 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 419
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x91386ee5 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 255
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x913866f8 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 311
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x913865bc -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 37
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x9137e6b1 loadNib + 482
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x9137dbbc +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 289
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x91598719 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoadingInternal) _loadNibFile:externalNameTable:options:withZone:] + 129
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x9163b5fe +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 43
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x9163b5ac _NXLoadNib + 169
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x9163b09a -[NSAlert init] + 97
27  ???                             0x085cc138 0 + 140296504
28  ???                             0x0b13c470 0 + 185844848
29  ???                             0x0b13aa70 0 + 185838192
30  ???                             0x0b13a800 0 + 185837568
31  ???                             0x0b13a738 0 + 185837368
32  ???                             0x0b139f5c 0 + 185835356
33  ???                             0x0b13a065 0 + 185835621
34  mono                            0x0002b3ff mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 751
35  mono                            0x001ee13f mono_runtime_invoke + 127
36  mono                            0x001f4fcd mono_runtime_invoke_array + 941
37  mono                            0x001679d5 ves_icall_InternalExecute + 309
38  ???                             0x0a37f690 0 + 171439760
39  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x019ac5b9 System_Runtime_Remoting_RemotingServices_InternalExecuteMessage_System_MarshalByRefObject_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMethodCallMessage + 521
40  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x01999865 System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_StackBuilderSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 245
41  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x01999424 System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_ServerObjectTerminatorSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 132
42  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x01989230 System_Runtime_Remoting_Lifetime_LeaseSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 64
43  ???                             0x0b139e9a 0 + 185835162
44  ???                             0x0b139e2c 0 + 185835052
45  ???                             0x0b139cf0 0 + 185834736
46  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x019b083a System_Runtime_Remoting_ClientActivatedIdentity_SyncObjectProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 154
47  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x01999287 System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_ServerContextTerminatorSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 423
48  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x0198615f System_Runtime_Remoting_Contexts_CrossContextChannel_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 239
49  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x0198d577 System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_ClientContextTerminatorSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 503
50  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x0198eeb7 System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_EnvoyTerminatorSink_SyncProcessMessage_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 55
51  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x019a377a System_Runtime_Remoting_Proxies_RemotingProxy_Invoke_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage + 970
52  mscorlib.dll.dylib              0x019a2164 System_Runtime_Remoting_Proxies_RealProxy_PrivateInvoke_System_Runtime_Remoting_Proxies_RealProxy_System_Runtime_Remoting_Messaging_IMessage_System_Exception__object___ + 1268
53  ???                             0x0a37f09f 0 + 171438239
54  mono                            0x0002b3ff mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 751
55  mono                            0x001ee13f mono_runtime_invoke + 127
56  mono                            0x001f78a1 mono_remoting_invoke + 145
57  mono                            0x001bc690 mono_remoting_wrapper + 192
58  ???                             0x0a37efd8 0 + 171438040
59  ???                             0x0b1396f0 0 + 185833200
60  ???                             0x0b139608 0 + 185832968
61  ???                             0x0b139248 0 + 185832008
62  ???                             0x0b13913c 0 + 185831740
63  ???                             0x0b1390e0 0 + 185831648
64  ???                             0x0b13802c 0 + 185827372
65  ???                             0x0333c154 0 + 53723476
66  ???                             0x005800a8 0 + 5767336
67  ???                             0x0057fe2c 0 + 5766700
68  ???                             0x0057ff07 0 + 5766919
69  mono                            0x0002b3ff mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 751
70  mono                            0x001ee13f mono_runtime_invoke + 127
71  mono                            0x001f41c1 mono_runtime_exec_main + 401
72  mono                            0x001f3f64 mono_runtime_run_main + 660
73  mono                            0x000a5e5d mono_jit_exec + 93
74  mono                            0x000a8130 mono_main + 7904
75  mono                            0x0001d730 main + 768
76  mono                            0x0001d425 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0xa760eeaa semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   mono                            0x0027116a mono_sem_wait + 26
2   mono                            0x001ec05a finalizer_thread + 154
3   mono                            0x001ca065 start_wrapper + 517
4   mono                            0x002766b0 inner_start_thread + 240
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa773174d _pthread_body + 292
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa7731629 _pthread_start + 376
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa7730d02 thread_start + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0xa761878e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa7731103 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0xa7730cde start_wqthread + 34



External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 89884
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=344.8M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=344.8M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=102.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=102.0M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
CG image                          1032K        3 
CoreAnimation                       32K        6 
CoreUI image file                  168K        3 
Foundation                           4K        2 
Image IO                          1036K        4 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            55.9M       33 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       12 
Stack                             14.0M       17 
Stack Guard                       56.2M       17 
VM_ALLOCATE                       29.6M       56 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             164K        6         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            13.7M      319 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
__LINKEDIT                        88.2M       45 
__OBJC                            6616K      136 
__TEXT                           256.6M      318 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
mapped file                      265.7M      259 
shared memory                      644K       12 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            790.1M     1235 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   790.0M     1235 

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B21, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3432372E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353436392D3036332E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.7.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.0d40, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: vivo Android Phone
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

I have already tried with permission on monoDevelop.app contents folder and applied to all sub folders as well.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thank you for mentioning up point. Will keep under consideration always before posting up any issue in coming future.

Comment: Not surprised as you run on a pre-release environment.

Answer (score 18):

I got this issue as well. Try removing your MonoDevelop data (this way works for me).

Open Terminal and run this:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/MonoDevelop-Unity-5.0
```

Comment: Wow. I keep running into this issue and so about once a week, I revisit this answer.

Comment: I installed the latest patch for 2017.2 but the problem is persisting and I have to rerun the rm command periodically.

Answer (score 8):

Update (Feb 2018):

As of 2018, Unity Technologies has been recommending **Visual Studio for Mac** as the preferred editor for Mac users. Before all those red flags and alarms tell you to flee out the door, please be advised that VS/Mac is a fork of Xamarin Studio (acquired by Microsoft), which in turn is a fork of MonoDevelop.

As it is a fork, VS/Mac is just an update of MonoDevelop, is more actively maintained, and has fewer crashes, memory leaks, and other productivity sinks. In my use for the past month, VS/Mac has been very stable, its memory footprint is quite stable as well, and there is no noticeable bloat as far as I can tell.

Finally, VS/Mac is available in three versions: Community, Professional, and Enterprise.

You can download VS/Mac from http://visualstudio.com 
The download and installation is just as simple as installing MonoDevelop or Xamarin.

Just go into Unity preferences, and choose VS/Mac as your external code editor, and you're good to go.

Give it a try.

---

Unity has issued patches to address the MonoDevelop crashes. The patches exist for the following versions of Unity:

- 2017.2
- 2017.1
- 5.6.3
- 5.5.4

If you're using a version that is not listed, you may have to change Unity versions, roll back Mac OS X, or use the Xamarin workaround.

Here's the URL to Unity patches:
https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Here's the Unity Forum link for more info:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-and-macos-10-13-high-sierra.474527/

Answer (score 2):

I've put a bounty on this, knowing full well there's some workarounds. I just prefer using the default integrated MonoDevelop and am hoping this can be solved. [Unity is already aware of the issue with MonoDevelop + High Sierra, but no solutions have been offered.](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-and-macos-10-13-high-sierra.474527/)

For those looking for a workaround, you download MonoDevelop + Xamarin Studio [straight from here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/), which works without crashing for me.

Comment: I know you prefer working with MonoDevelop but have you given a try to Visual Studio Code with the Unity extension?

Although is not perfect, I tried it out and never looked back, it now supports debugging, syntax auto completion, etc...

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Comment: WARNING/CAVEAT: I found this was a workable solution until I wanted to debug my app using the *Attach to process...* method. I am using Xamarin Studio 6.3, and it does not support Unity debugging out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple monitors one cause for MonoDevelop crashing is having the IDE open in a secondary monitor during previous session.
In this case you don't need to remove all your preferences but instead edit MonoDevelopProperties.xml and remove the "bounds" property within the WorkbenchMemento node:

```
 <Property key="bounds" value="-37, 162, 1920, 1020" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two or more monitors, try moving Unity IDE to another monitor and then launch MonoDevelop.
For some reason, if you closed MonoDevelop main window on a different monitor and try to start it again on another monitor, it crashes.